# How to use S3 bucket URL as the base URL for images on components

Tags: vue.js

I am using S3 bucket to save user's profile images and the image they are uploading. On my components I want to use the image base url to the S3 bucket

I declared a variable on main.js

```
window.s3bucket = 'https://myassets.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com';
```

and then in component I am trying to use it as :

```
<img alt=""  :src="s3bucket+'/user/'+ userimage">
```

but I am getting error as s3bucket is not defined or its not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. Don't hang variables off the window if you're not in a UMD environment.

Instead, you could just assign this to `vue` directly:

```
Vue.prototype.$s3bucket =  'https://myassets.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com';
```

Notice I've used `$` above so you don't have potential collisions.

Then just use:

```
:src=`${$s3bucket}/user/${userimage}...`
```

(You don't have to use template strings, I just prefer the syntax)

Comment: now it says "Property or method "$s3bucket$" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render"